# Selecting value once with multiple entries MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

A user can create a form that allows other users to register. So, if a user creates a form, he can also register on said form.

Say I have the following tables

```
//Form 
id | title  | entry             | userid
1     test     entry for form        1

//form_register - Allows users to register for a particular form, form_id references form.id
form_id | userid
   1        1
   1        1
   1        2
   1        2
```

Now, suppose I want to generate a list for forms users have created AND signed up for. Users can sign up for the same form more than once, but I only want to display the form once. I don't want a list of every single time a user signs up for, only a list of the forms they signed up for, not the actual signups.

**If a user creates a form, then signs up for that same form 2 times I only want the form information to display 1 time. My current query displays the form info 3 times (one for creating, 2 for registering).**

```
    SELECT form.*, form_register.* FROM forms
    INNER JOIN form_register on form_regiseter.form_id = form.id
    WHERE form_register.userid = '$userid'
```

When this query runs for user 1, it generates the following

```
Title  
test
test
test
```

I just want it to display the form once like this

```
Title
test
```

For userid2 this would be the output

```
Title
test
test
```

And I want it to be

```
Title
test
```

Comment: You don't store a "type" field that specifies if they are registering or creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT form.*, form_register.* FROM forms
    INNER JOIN form_register on form_regiseter.form_id = form.id
    WHERE form_register.userid = '$userid'
```

may be what you're looking for

Comment: Perfect, that was it. Thanks, I'll accept as soon as the time limit goes away

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to get unique rows.

Alternatively, you could also disallow duplicate entries in the `form_register` table by applying a `UNIQUE`-index. You can rewrite your `INSERT` queries to `REPLACE` queries and you will never get duplicate rows.

`REPLACE` will `INSERT` a row if it doesn't exist, or replace it (based on the `PRIMARY KEY`) if it does.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a bit more clear. A user can register for a form multiple times. It's kind of like a sign in/out type of system, so aside from the date, duplicates will be necessary.